# Xerces-C problems; segfault on call to object destructor

Tags: c++, xml, segmentation-fault, xerces-c

I've been playing around with the [Xerces-C](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) XML library.

I have this simple example I'm playing with.

I can't seem to get it to run without leaking memory and without segfaulting.
It's one or the other.

The segfault always occurs when I delete the parser object under "Clean up".

I've tried using both the 2.8 & 2.7 versions of the library.

**Note:** I took all of the exception checking out of the code, I get the same results with it and without it. For readability and simplicity I removed it from the code below.

**Any Xerces-savvy people out there care to make some suggestions?**

I can't really tell much from the back trace, it's just jumping down into the superclass destructor and segfaulting there.

**Backtrace:**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x9618ae42 in __kill ()
#1  0x9618ae34 in kill$UNIX2003 ()
#2  0x961fd23a in raise ()
#3  0x96209679 in abort ()
#4  0x95c5c005 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
#5  0x95c5a10c in __gxx_personality_v0 ()
#6  0x95c5a14b in std::terminate ()
#7  0x95c5a6da in __cxa_pure_virtual ()
#8  0x003e923e in xercesc_2_8::AbstractDOMParser::cleanUp ()
#9  0x003ead2a in xercesc_2_8::AbstractDOMParser::~AbstractDOMParser ()
#10 0x0057022d in xercesc_2_8::XercesDOMParser::~XercesDOMParser ()
#11 0x000026c9 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff460) at test.C:77
```

**The code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector> 

#if defined(XERCES_NEW_IOSTREAMS)
#include <iostream>
#else
#include <iostream.h>
#endif

#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMDocument.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMElement.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp>
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/sax/HandlerBase.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/OutOfMemoryException.hpp>
#include <xercesc/framework/MemBufInputSource.hpp>

using namespace std;

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{

  string skXmlMetadata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n <xmlMetadata>b</xmlMetadata>";

  XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  XercesDOMParser* xmlParser = NULL;
  DOMWriter* xmlWriter = NULL; 
  ErrorHandler* errHandler = NULL;
  const XMLByte* xmlBuf =  NULL;
  MemBufInputSource* memBufIS = NULL;
  DOMNode* xmlDoc = NULL;

  xmlParser = new XercesDOMParser();
  xmlParser->setValidationScheme( XercesDOMParser::Val_Never );
  xmlParser->setDoNamespaces( false );
  xmlParser->setDoSchema( false );
  xmlParser->setLoadExternalDTD( false );

  errHandler = (ErrorHandler*) new HandlerBase();
  xmlParser->setErrorHandler( errHandler );

  // Create buffer for current xmlMetadata
  xmlBuf = (const XMLByte*) skXmlMetadata.c_str();
  const char* bufID = "XmlMetadata";
  memBufIS = new MemBufInputSource( xmlBuf, skXmlMetadata.length(), bufID, false );

  // Parse
  xmlParser->resetErrors();
  xmlParser->parse( *memBufIS );
  xmlDoc = xmlParser->getDocument();

  // Write created xml to input SkArray
  XMLCh* metadata = NULL;
  xmlWriter = DOMImplementation::getImplementation()->createDOMWriter();
  xmlWriter->setFeature( XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint, true );
  metadata = xmlWriter->writeToString( *xmlDoc );
  xmlWriter->release();


  // Print out our parsed document
  char* xmlMetadata = XMLString::transcode( metadata );
  string c = xmlMetadata;
  cout << c << endl;

  // Clean up
  XMLString::release( &xmlMetadata );
  xmlDoc->release();
  delete xmlParser; // Dies here
  delete memBufIS;
  delete errHandler;
  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may help folks zero in on your problem if you can point out which is line 77 in your source.  Maybe an end-of-line comment like "//dies here"?

Comment: So I'm not familiar with Xerces, but have you tried using RAII with a std::auto_ptr or similar? 

If you want to avoid that, I typically delete items in the reverse order I new them. There may be some weird interaction that's happening between the xmlParser and the error handler, because you delete the xmlParser before the errorHandler?

Comment: Xerces parsers don't own their error handlers, so this is in fact the correct order.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the code and just open and close the xerces document to see if you can isolate the error.  If I get the chance later I will look for code I wrote that uses xerces in a similar way.

Comment: @Matt I added the die comment. @Maggie yea everything works as expected in a simplified version.

Comment: I think you should delete the parser after the errhandler and before terminate.

I'd also suggest you check the errhandler after the parse call.

 xmlParser->parse( *memBufIS );
// check errors here
 xmlDoc = xmlParser->getDocument();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

" xmlDoc->release(); " is the culprit. You dont own that Node unless you say " xmlParser->adoptDocument() "

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classAbstractDOMParser.html#fe052561c37d70b62ac57ab6706d75aa

Comment: Wow, awesome catch. That was totally the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets explore the evidence...

```
#6  0x95c5a14b in std::terminate ()
```

I can tell you this is called when a destructor throws an exception. Destructors throwing exceptions is a big no-no. Xerces may be doing something wonky.

Or it might be caused by this line

```
#7  0x95c5a6da in __cxa_pure_virtual ()
```

where something might be missing in a virtual function table. Perhaps one of the DOM object's members destructor? Perhaps this generates an exception?

[This link](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/pure_virtual.html) offers a great explanation on what might cause the virtual table lookups to fail. In short, it can be caused by a dangling base-class pointer hanging around someone trying to make a polymorphic function call on that pointer.

Example given from the link above:

```
// From sample program 5:
AbstractShape* p1 = new Rectangle(width, height, valuePerSquareUnit);
std::cout << "value = " << p1->value() << std::endl;
AbstractShape* p2 = p1;  // Need another copy of the pointer.
delete p1;
std::cout << "now value = " << p2->value() << std::endl;
```

Speaking of dangling pointers, it looks like the XercesDomParser is holding objects you newed:

```
  errHandler = (ErrorHandler*) new HandlerBase();
  xmlParser->setErrorHandler( errHandler )
```

but later deleted/released

```
  // Clean up
  XMLString::release( &xmlMetadata );
  xmlDoc->release();
  delete xmlParser;
  delete memBufIS;
  delete errHandler;
```

Could the order you are destroying things be incorrect and cause some of the above problems? On the face of it, things look OK, but that's where I would experiment and double check the documentation on how things are supposed to be torn down.

Comment: Xerces parsers do not own their error handlers and will not delete them.

Comment: I tried a try/catch block around the delete of xmlParser before I asked the question, as @Doug T mentioned no exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code. You might like to try removing all the uses of new & delete in the code and create the Cerces objects you use as stack based objectys instead. For example, instead of:

```
xmlParser = new XercesDOMParser();
```

use:

```
XercesDOMParser xmlParser;
```

and so on.

Comment: Tried that, still segfaults in the deconstructor of the stack based XercesDOMParser :(